# JavaScript textarea editor with custom formatting rules

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, editor, textarea

i need to implement simple text editor with custom (probably dynamic) rules. For example, if user change text somehow i want to run regex (or callback method or something else) on this text and apply formatting for it. For ex all ip addresses in text should have red color, names from specified range - black, all words starting from "abc" - green.

So basically what i need is:
- simple text editor based on text area
- ability so add rules applying to text withing text area

I reviewed a lot of related resources and didn't found any simple solution yet. As for now I've started to implement my own editor with using of contenteditable attribute and JQuery.

I never wrote such functionality before, so could you please point me to the right direction? Maybe i can use already implemented tools or specific strategy?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be useful for someone.
After a bit of investigation at first i tried to use jQuery Highlight Plugin, but it does not cover my all of needs so i used [Codemirror](http://codemirror.net/) editor, which i found very nice and customizable.

I wrote my custom mode and it's working perfectly.

As start point i used this [article](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/blog/codemirror-mode-system.html)